# python - creating named array for every row from pandas data frame

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a dataframe like this:

```
index  a   b   c
1      2   3   4
2      3   4   5
```

I am trying to derive an array for each row along with the column name.  The desired output for the above example would be

```
[["a":2,"b":3,"c":4],["a":3,"b":4,"c":5]]
```

I am trying to get it done through a for loop, but I am getting the following:

```
for rows, index in df.iterrows():
    print(index)

a    2
b    3
v    4
Name: 0, dtype: float64
a    3
b    4
c    5
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it all wrong here

```
for rows, index in df.iterrows(): 
  print(index)
```

Whereas it should be

```
for index, rows in df.iterrows(): 
  print(index)
```

A common mistake, that people make.

If you want to show all it's contents, within a single line, typecast to dict

```
for index, rows in df.iterrows(): 
  print(index)
  row = dict(rows)
  print(row)
```

Comment: thank you...i will accept this as answer.  Thank you again